# Syntax highlighting in Vscode for type hints

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, themes, syntax-highlighting

I am using the Dark++ theme but personalising a lot of colours.
Everything works fine but one small thing: only the basic types are properly highlighted.
For example this

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "comments": "#707070",
      "keywords": "#adc5ee",
      "types": "#bbbbbb",
      "strings": "#bdceb7"
}
```

gives me the following picture:
[image]

I would like the type hints in the function declaration to be grey+italic, as it happens correctly for the type "str". I understand it is not straightforward for npt.NDArray as that comes from the typing module, but why is this not working even for "list" and "dict"?
And do you know of a workaround I could use?
There are not special tokens for these types as far as I know, so no way to access them other than just customising the general token "types".
I tried using regex expressions with the "Highlight" extension but that is not optimal, because I also want to keep the functionality that if I comment out part of that text, it should be greyed-out (using "Highlight" it doesn't).

Comment: my PyLance tells me to quote the type hints: `def myFunc(arg1: 'dict[str, float]', arg2: 'list[dict[str,str]]') -> None:`, the semantic scope is different, so use the semantic color customization

Comment: @rioV8 that's great! However, do you know how to avoid the semantic color customization to override the workbench.colorCustomizations? I would like the latter to have precedence

Comment: the `editor` and `workbench` customizations apply to different parts of the editor, in the editor you have `token` and `semantic` customizations

Comment: Whoops sorry, I meant that semantic seemed to override the editor.tokenColorCustomizations (I mistakenly wrote "workbench"). In any case, apparently a reset solved it :)
Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To close this topic and for future reference, this is how I solved my issue: I ended up using semantic highlighting for type hints as rioV8 suggested.

This is done by adding the following to my Vscode settings JSON file:

```
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
      "rules": {
        "*.typeHint": {
          "foreground": "#bbbbbb",
          "fontStyle": "italic"
        },
        "class.typeHint.builtin": {
          "foreground": "#bbbbbb",
          "fontStyle": "italic"
        }
      }
    }
```